# TSQL + Entity Framework Join tables and concatenate rows into one string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I am trying to join 3 tables in a query to get a cohesive output that summarizes the employees and their titles. The setup is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (id INT, name VARCHAR(16))
CREATE TABLE titles (employeeId INT, standardTitleId INT)
CREATE TABLE standard_titles(standardTitleId INT, title VARCHAR(16))
GO

INSERT INTO standard_titles VALUES
    (0, 'Co-Founder'),
    (1, 'CEO'),
    (2, 'CTO'),
    (3, 'CFO')
INSERT INTO employees VALUES 
    (0, 'Bill'),
    (1, 'Bob'),
    (2, 'Sue')
INSERT INTO titles VALUES
    (0, 0),
    (0, 1),
    (1, 0),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3)
GO
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
id    name      titles
================================
0     Bill      Co-Founder, CEO
1     Bob       Co-Founder, CTO
2     Sue       CFO
```

After reading through posts, I have managed to come close but also managed to finagle something:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name, 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + s.title
        FROM standard_titles s
            INNER JOIN titles t ON t.standardTitleId = s.standardTitleId
            INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id = t.employeeId
        WHERE t.standardTitleId = s.standardTitleId
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM employees e
```

which gives me this:

```
id  name    (No column name)
===========================================================
0   Bill       Co-Founder, CEO, Co-Founder, CTO, CFO
1   Bob        Co-Founder, CEO, Co-Founder, CTO, CFO
2   Sue        Co-Founder, CEO, Co-Founder, CTO, CFO
```

The questions:

1. What I am doing wrong in the `FOR XML PATH` part.
2. Once the TSQL is fixed, is there a way to do this via Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2):

So, here is half an answer, only for your first question:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name, 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + s.title
        FROM standard_titles s
            INNER JOIN titles t ON t.standardTitleId = s.standardTitleId
            --INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id = t.employeeId
        WHERE e.id = t.employeeId
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM employees e
```

[And here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f5dd/2) for you to try.

Comment: Thanks Lamak, HLGEM's answer below makes more sense. And thanks for the sqlfiddle link - that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name, 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + s.title
        FROM standard_titles s
            INNER JOIN titles t ON t.standardTitleId = s.standardTitleId
        WHERE e.id = t.employeeId
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM employees e
```

You were not correlating to the outer employees table.

Comment: Thanks HLGEM! Now to see how to do this in EF.